# Having trouble in writing String ArrayList into File

Tags: java, file, arraylist, writefile

I don't know why it doesn't write the `ArrayList` into the `File`.
Can someone point out where is the mistake?

```
public class Course {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instructor instruct = new Instructor();
        TextBook text = new TextBook();

        // Ask for course name
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter course's name: ");
        String name = sc.nextLine();

        try {
            // Create a File name Courses List
            FileWriter file = new FileWriter(
                    "C:\\Users\\gltha\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\JAVA\\Course Register Office\\src\\Courses List");
            while (true) {
                // Create an ArrayList name courseList to store the input
                ArrayList<String> courseList = new ArrayList<String>();
                String course = name + " || " + instruct.instructor() + " || " + text.textbook();
                // Add input into ArrayList
                courseList.add(course);
                // Print out the input
                System.out.println(courseList);
                for (String str : courseList);
                // Write the ArrayList into File
                file.write(courseList + System.lineSeparator());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try(BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\gltha\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\JAVA\\Course Register Office\\src\\Courses List")){ for (String str : courseList){ bufferedWriter.write(str}; }}finally{bufferedWriter.flush();//this flushes the buffer}

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see you are trying to write the message on a ***folder*** not a ***file***. You need to specify the file path as the following.

```
"C:\\Users\\gltha\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\JAVA\\Course Register Office\\src\\Courses List\\courseList.txt"
```